# Android, library-com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0 shows duplicate hint in android api versions below 21

Tags: android, android-edittext, libphonenumber

[image]

I am facing this problem while using "library-com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.0" for phone number validation, in Android API version below 20 the Edittext shows the double hint. here is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 26
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.2'                        // phone number validator
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by double hint? Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I mean hint supposed to be 8123456789, and the hint on Android API versions higher than 20 it works properly eg "8123456789" but in Android API version lower than 21 the hint shown is "81234567898123456789".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug which is fixed. Please upgrade to newer version. As of today it's 2.2.7.

```
dependencies {
      implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.2.7'
    }
```